# одинаковые значения в <select>, полученные из msql

Tags: php, sql

Добрый день.
Прошу Вашей помощи в следующем вопросе:
Есть выпадающий список, который я получаю в результате выборки из БД SQL

```html
    <?php
 echo'
<select name="id_auto" id="id_auto">
<option value="Выберите марку...">Выберите марку...</option>
';

                $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `location` WHERE `acct`='".$username."'");
                $answer = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

                do {
                    echo '<option value="'.$answer["id"].'">'.$answer["did"].'</option>';
                }
                while ($answer = mysql_fetch_assoc($query));




echo '</select>';?>
```

В результате я получаю уйму повторяющихся значений. Как из всего списка значений заставить "вываливаться" по одному экземпляру каждого, то бишь вместо

```html
        Honda
        Honda
        Honda
        Honda
        Honda
        Honda
        Honda
        Honda
        Honda
        Yamaxa
        Yamaxa
        Yamaxa
        Yamaxa
        Yamaxa
        Yamaxa
        Yamaxa
        Yamaxa
        Yamaxa
        Yamaxa
        Yamaxa
        Yamaxa
        Yamaxa
        Yamaxa
        Suzuki
        Suzuki
        Suzuki
        Suzuki
        Suzuki
```

в селект выпадало только :

```html
        Honda
        Yamaxa
        Suzuki
```

Comment: Начните с запроса. надо понять почему он возвращает много записей. может надо применить distinct, правда выбирать в этом случае (да и вообще во всех случаях) надо не `*`, а только те колонки которые нужны

Comment: `select distinct * ...` ?

Comment: Вот что у вас за поле `id`, оно одинаково для одинаковых значений `did` т.е. вашего текста в option

Comment: @AndreyM при правильной структуре таблицы `select distinct *` даст столько же записей, потому что в таблице есть хотя бы одна уникальная колонка

Comment: `GROUP BY did` не поможет?

Comment: id - это разные значения, did- эьл те самые Honda
  Yamaxa
  Suzuki

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо огромное , помог код

```html
SELECT * FROM `location` WHERE `acct`='".$username."' GROUP BY `did`
```

Comment: Может он конечно и помог, но вы сказали, что у вас для одного did разные id. и id вы используете. надеюсь вас устраивают два факта: 1. В options у вас любой случайный id для конкретного did. 2. В новых версиях MySQL это запрос может быть не рабочим так как требуется явно перечислять колонки и те, что не участвуют в group by должны быть в агрегатных функциях

Comment: @Mike Самое интересное, что в заголовке вопроса у автора указан вообще MSSQL, где такой запрос вообще не может работать. :)